# What is the cause of a 404 error when calling an API in R?

Tags: python, r

I made an API request code using R and Python, respectively.

In the following code, Python returns 200, but R returns 404. What's the problem?
(For convenience, the library call syntax is omitted.)

#### Python code

```
payload = { '\`access_key\`: 'access_key',     'nonce': `str`(`uuid.uuid4()`) }

jwt_token = `jwt.encode`(payload, 'secret_key')

authorization_token = 'Bearer {}'.`format`(jwt_token)

headers = {"accept": "application/json",
"Authorization": authorization_token}

res = `requests.get`('https://api.upbit.com/v1/accounts', headers=headers)
```

#### R code

```
payload = `jwt_claim`(access_key = 'access_key',
                    nonce = `uuid::UUIDgenerate`(output="string"))

jwt_token = `jose::jwt_encode_hmac`(payload, secret = 'secret_key')

headers = `add_headers`(accept = "application/json", Authorization = `sprintf`("Bearer %s", jwt_token))

headers2 = c(accept = "application/json", Authorization = `sprintf`("Bearer %s", jwt_token))

url = "https://api.upbit.com/V1/accounts"

res1 = `GET`(url=url, headers=headers);res1

res2 = `GET`(url=url, add_headers(.headers = headers2));res2
```

What is the correction for the syntax error in the R code?

Comment: Hi 냉면은물냉면! Welcome to StackOverflow. You're asking about an API where all of the documentation is in Korean, and it's impossible to use the API without sending your passport information to the company. I don't know how much use anyone here can be in these circumstances

Comment: Are the backticks actually part of the code? For the Python part, I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (Python 3.6.9 (yes, I know)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

The issue in your R code seems to be with the capitalization of the URL path. In the Python code, you're using `'https://api.upbit.com/v1/accounts'` with a lowercase `v1`, whereas in your R code, you're using `"https://api.upbit.com/V1/accounts"` with an uppercase `V1`. URLs are case-sensitive, so make sure the capitalization matches. Use `"https://api.upbit.com/v1/accounts"` in your R code to match the Python code and likely resolve the 404 error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, justyce jaelen!

Your 7 answers so far appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). *Six* of those seven have comments from users indicating issues with the answer, which demonstrates why [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!